# Is there a way to chop off String Array in java(without using loops) and convert directly to integer?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here is what i want to achieve.

Input:

```
5
1 2 3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9
```

Expected Output:

```
The list is 1 2 3 -4 -5.
There are 3 positive numbers and 2 negative numbers.
```

Sample Code:

```
String[] s = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    ...
}
System.out.printf("The list is %s.\nThere are %d positive numbers and %d negative numbers",(s.toString().substring(0,n)),pos,neg);
sc.close();
```

Output now:

```
The list is [Ljav.
There are 3 positive numbers and 2 negative numbers.
```

Tried applying `Integer.parseint(s.toString().substring(0,n))` with `%d` but then also got the same output as above. How to correct this?

Comment: change `s.toString()` to `Arrays.toString(s)`

Comment: Side note: You may want to use `%n` instead of `\n` when using `printf`

Comment: @Eran its still giving ```The list is [1, 2.``` as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.asList` and `stream` API to get to the solution. I have used `limit` to limit the number of record to 5 as in your case. If your condition changes, you can use `filter` and have your condition placed there. Below is a small code snippet of how it can be done

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = "1 2 3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9".split(" ");
    Arrays.asList(s).stream().limit(5).forEach(System.out::print); // filter
   // or use below to get the first five element list
   Arrays.asList(s).stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: It is wanted that solution does not have loops when printing.

Comment: @Ekrem Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try string manipulation.

```
@Test
public void stringManipulationForArray() {

    int[] intArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    final String arrayAsStr = Arrays.toString(intArray);
    System.out.println(arrayAsStr );
    final String numbersWithCommas = arrayAsStr .substring(1, s.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(numbersWithCommas);
    final String numbersWithoutCommas = numbersWithCommas.replace(",", "");
    System.out.println(numbersWithoutCommas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Arrays.toString(s)` instead of `s.toString()`.

Corrected code would look like this:

```
String[] s = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    ...
}
System.out.printf("The list is %s.\nThere are %d positive numbers and %d negative numbers",(Arrays.toString(s).substring(0,n)),pos,neg);
sc.close();
```

Comment: its still giving The list is [1, 2. as output.

Comment: Well, thats because you get the substring from 0 to n (`substring(0,n)`).
`Arrays.toString(s)` should give you this string: `[1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]`.
Now you can use substring to cut off the parts of the string you don't want, and you should get `1, 2, 3, -4, -5`.

Comment: I think `substring(1, n*3 + neg - 1)` should work for you.